# Why is my getline not reading .csv files properly?

Tags: c++

I opened my `input.csv` file correctly and it has contents inside.
However, when I `cout` what I read, they are all empty.

The input file is a questionnaire feedback with question names on the first line and corresponding points below.

An example of the input file is:

Name,Q1,Q2

Ann,7,6

Ben,5,6

```
int main(){
    string input_file;
    string output_file;
    cout<<"input file name"<<endl;
    cin>>input_file;
    output_file = input_file.insert(input_file.length()-4, "_out");

    ifstream fin(input_file);
    if(fin.is_open()){
        cout<<"the file name is correct. ";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"the file name does not exist.";
        return 0;
    }
    ofstream fout(output_file);
    int sample_size = 0;
    int highest_point = 0;

    cout<<"What is the highest point possible?"<<endl;
    cin>>highest_point;

    vector<Tag*> tags;
    string first_line;
    string tag_name;
    getline(fin, first_line);
    //as reminded, I added a check here;
    if (!std::getline(fin, first_line)) { std::cerr << "Failed to read first line\n"; std::exit(1); }
    //this does prints out the error message so I guess the getline function is not even working correctly.

    //When I cout first_line here, it prints nothing on my terminal
    cout<<first_line;
    istringstream stringIn1(first_line);
    while(getline(stringIn1, tag_name, ',')){
        //WHEN I COUT tag_name HERE, IT PRINTS NOTHING ON MY TERMINAL EITHER
        cout<<tag_name;
        tags.push_back(new Tag(tag_name));

    }
```

Comment: *"WHEN I COUT first_line HERE"* - *where* ???. The code does no such thing. And you never check the result of `std::getline(fin, first_line)` for success before the phantom output we can't see anyway. Post a [mcve] and include the data file [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56862828/edit)

Comment: Ok post-edit #1, still not checking the results of the `getline` extraction. `if (!std::getline(fin, first_line)) { std::cerr << "Failed to read first line\n"; std::exit(1); }` . Never assume your IO (particularly the "I" in IO) works. Assumption is the mother of all....

Comment: Please read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking your next question.

Comment: @YingyingZhu -- `input_file.length()-4` -- Your code fails miserably if someone enters as the input file `a.b`.

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
output_file = input_file.insert(input_file.length()-4, "_out");
```

is not doing what you expect it to do, you are modifying the name of the input_file so that output_file and input_file are the same. Therefore the same file is opened. Check always also the return value from getline, it is good practice.

Copy first the string to output_file, then do the insert on the output_file instead.

Comment: Almost, both file streams are opened but opening the output stream empties the file so `getline` returns nothing due to end of file

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah, still the problem is the same name but I updated the answer, thanks.